# Celery how to remove results of tasks in redis after read

Tags: python, celery

I integrate Celery to distribute tasks and use Redis as result backend. Now everything works. But after running some tasks, Redis is full of results which have been read. How can I remove these results after reading them.

I want something like this:

```
async_result.get_and_delete()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`forget` can remove results from redis.

```
result = async_result.get()
async_result.forget()
```